# Vector of ifstreams

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

How can I create and manipulate a vector of ifstreams?

Something like this, except this doesn't work:

```
vector<ifstream> Files(10, ifstream());
Files[0].open("File");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I can think of is `vector<shared_ptr<ifstream> >` — you can't put `ifstream`s in vector as they're not copy-constructible.

Comment: Just an interesting tid-bit: in C++ 0x, we will be able to put streams in containers, because even though they're not copy-constructible, they will be move-constructible.

Comment: Jerry, thanks, I know I should take a closer look at this brave new world, but I keep postponing it. (P.S. I also started with Fortran IV:))

Comment: Given that we are running out of decimal values of 'x' in 'C++ 0x', I think it's fair to say that you're not the only person doing the postponing, hacker. ;)

Comment: That's a great consolation, Kylotan ;-)

Comment: BTW, Kylotan, shouldn't values of `x` in `0x` be octal, not decimal?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot store `ifstream`s in a `std::vector`, because you can not create copies of them.

You can accomplish something similar by storing pointers instead. In that case, I recommend you use some sort of a pointer container to make sure that those ifstreams get deleted.

Comment: +1: ...although without knowing the context it's hard to say whether a smart pointer is really required. That might just be complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, you can use `emplace_back`:

```
vector<ifstream> Files;
Files.emplace_back("File1");
// ...

// Use the files here...

// Close them afterwards:
for (auto &file : Files) file.close();
```